# Should we call Bash Special parameters, "environment constants"?

Tags: bash, terminology

After reading [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) and then [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html), I came to the conclusion, that what is called in Bash "Special parameters" is quite like environment variables, but the main difference is that we shouldn't **reassign** Special parameters - A thing we could otherwise do without restriction (but with much caution) for environment variables.

Hence, this is my question:

Should we call Bash special parameters, "environment constants" (at least metaphorically)?

Comment: The documentation calls them special parameters. Why would anyone want to use terminology different from the reference documentation?

Comment: I don't want that, I just used this term as an analogy to see if I understand the original term correct, but I didn't, as implied from the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. "Environment" has a specific meaning, referring to a set of variables that are passed down to child processes at which point the variables are stored in their process space. Calling other variables "environment" would be misleading and inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

They're not actually constants, since you can modify them with the `set` command, e.g.:

```bsh
user@ehost:~$ set x y z
user@ehost:~$ echo $1 $2 $3
x y z
```

They are parameters though, since they're passed in when the shell is invoked.

Comment: Thank you Igal. it helped me understand it better so I upvoted.